# Ember input type number to allow only 2 digits after Decimal

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am working on an Ember application, an input type number as below

```
 ${{input type="number" id=p.ViolationTypeId 
          value=p.PenaltyAssessed maxlength="5" 
          scale="0.01" pattern="^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$" 
          key-down=(action 'allowOnly2Decimals') 
          focusOut=(action 'saveTotalPenalty' p model.id p.PenaltyAssessed)}}
```

Then I have a following JavaScript Code written to limit the entry of digits after decimal, this function is called in Key-Down event.

```
    allowOnly2Decimals: function (e1, event) {
            var boxId = '#' + event.path[0].id;

            //if ((event.keyCode == 190) || (event.keyCode == 110)) {
            //    this.decimalPressed = true;
            //}

            var t = e1.toString().split('.');

            if (t[1] != null) {
                if (t[1].length == 2) {
                    this.limitDecimal = e1;
                    $(boxId).val(e1);
                }

                if (t[1].length >= 2) {
                    e1 = this.limitDecimal;
                    $(boxId).val(e1);

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Its working but what it is doing it, it allowing 3 digits after decimal but when I am posting its value on the Service, that is taking correctly 2 digits after decimal but what it is showing in the Textbox is 3 digits after decimal.
And another request if possible is, can I do the same without using id attribute on the Textbox.

Any help please, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, the reason it is allowing 3 values is because you are using the `keydown` event. The `keydown` event is fired before the input is updated so you're always 1 character behind the actual value. I would recommend instead of using keydown, to use the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event). If you really have to mangle the user's inputs as they type, use the keyup event instead.

To answer your second question, you can access the input via `event.target` i.e. `$(event.target).val(e1);`

Finally your code is making some assumptions about the user's input, what happens if they paste in a value that is longer than 2 characters after the decimal?